# Export a list of IntelliJ plugins

Tags: intellij-idea

One feature I miss from Eclipse is exporting a list of installed plugins; I haven't been able to find a way to do this in IntelliJ.

For developers who need to use different machines (including different OSs) this would be helpful.  Other than the availables.xml and disabled_plugins.txt is there any other way to get a list of what plugins are installed and active?  Having to use two files to deduce the answers is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no easier way to do it right now, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-35331).

Comment: 2021-0-3-29. 154 users voted it already. The issue is almost becoming a teenageer. Any ETA?

Answer (score 37):

Open the settings, go to plugins, filter them by "Enabled", then select the entire list (CTRL+A would work), and copy them with CTRL+C.

This will give you a nice list of enabled plugins along with their versions. Something like:

```
BashSupport (1.6.13.182)
Behat Support (182.4129.45)
Blade Support (182.4129.45)
Codeception Framework (182.4129.45)
CoffeeScript (182.4129.45)
Command Line Tool Support (182.4129.45)
[...]
```

Comment: Simple and best answer! On the mac, just press cmd + a and cmd + v

Comment: Great call, I suggest filtering by downloaded instead so as to not to include the bundled plugins, you will have to remove the disabled ones manually from the pasted list however

Comment: @boardtc /downloaded /enabled

Answer (score 4):

I think there is plugin now here:
[Intellij plugin export](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7891-plugin-importer-exporter/versions)

You can download and install that, after restart IDEA, you can see the option under File -> Export Plugins...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: That is an abandoned plugin not up-to-date (last update: 2019.10.22)

Answer (score 2):

i find intellij plugin in this directory (windows 7):

> C:\Users\{USER_NAME}\.IntelliJIdea{IDEA_VERSION}\config\plugins